# limits at infinity

Tags: limits

(a) ♦Write down the precise definitions of
(i) lim f(x) = L, (ii) lim f(x) = ∞. where this two is x approaching ∞

(b) ♦Use the precise definition to show that lim x/(2x+1) = 1, this is also x approaching ∞

i write out the definition of limit at infinity. where M is a number such that f(x) greater than M. but i dont know how to do because all involves algebra instead of numbers. how do i continue or start? thanks.

Comment: in b, we have limit equal to 1/2, not 1

Comment: Also there is not such a thing like limit $L =  ∞$, limit must be real number, if it exist. In  ∞ case, limit don't exists, $f$ grows without bound.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz The limit does not have to be a real number.  When one writes $\lim f=\infty$ it means that given any number, however large, we can find a point in the domain such that $f$ exceeds that number.

Comment: sorry sorry the first question is approaching negative infinity

Comment: for part I is negative infinity but part ii still is approaching infinity

Comment: Are you sure it's $\frac x{2x+1}$? That's equal to $\frac12-\frac1{4x+2}$, as you can check, so it goes to $\frac12$.

Comment: umm they already clarified in the first comment. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Definition:  The limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=L$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $B>0$, such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $x>B$.

---

**APPLICATION:**

Claim:  $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{2x+1}=\frac12$.

Proof:  Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Then, for $x\ge1/2$

\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x}{2x+1}-\frac12\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{2(2x+1)}\right|\\\\
&\le\frac{1}{8x}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}

whenever $x>B=\max\left(\frac12,\frac{8}{\epsilon}\right)$.  And we are done.

Comment: Interesting, I've always seen $N$ instead of $B$. (Not that it makes the slightest bit of difference.)

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.